# Loading files from AWS S3 bucket to a Snowflake tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to copy files from S3 bucket to the Snowflake. To do this I'm using Lambda function. In the S3 bucket I have a folders and in every folders there are many CSV files. These CSV files can small and huge. I have created a Lambda function that is loading these files to the Snowflake. The problem is that Lambda function can work only 15 minutes. It's not enough to load all the files to the Snowflake. Can you help me with this problem? I have one solution for this - execute lambda only with one file not with all files

Comment: Not sure what is your use case and limitations, but using a Lambda function is probably not the best approach to copy files from S3 into Snowflake, there are other ways. Have you looked at the documentation [Bulk Loading from Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3.html)? You could create a stage and then either COPY INTO a table in Snowflake or create an external table in Snowflake.

Comment: Thank you for response. I want to automated that. I was thinking about Snowpipe but it will not work for me, that why I have created a Lambda function that will be triggered after a file cames to the folder in S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the maximum execution time for a Lambda function is 15 minutes, and is not a good idea load all the file in the memory, because you will have high costs with execution time and high usage of memory.

But, if you really want to use Lambdas and you are dealing with files over 1GB, perhaps you should consider [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena) or optimizing your AWS Lambda function to read the file using a [stream](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/streaming-data-from-amazon-s3-to-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-using-aws-dms/) instead of loading the whole file into memory.

Other option may be to create a SQS message when the file lands on s3 and have an EC2 instance poll the queue and process as necessary. For more information check here: [Running Cost-effective queue workers with Amazon SQS and Amazon EC2 Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-cost-effective-queue-workers-with-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-ec2-spot-instances/).

The best option will be automate the Snowpipe with AWS Lambda, for this check the Snowpipe docs [Automating Snowpipe with AWS Lambda](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-lambda.html).